# Add filter to Spring security to implement multi tenant

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, multi-tenant

I need to update my Spring Security configuration to introduce multi-tenant management (where I get URL for each web request and through a configuration file I retrieve the correct schema).
So I add a filter (because with handler the login page doesn't have the correct schema since the handler is called after spring security) to my spring security configuration but now I catch the URL, set the schema but the page still empty and doesn't redirect to login page and also if I write /login no HTML page appears.

This is how I have configured spring security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private RoleServices roleServices;
    @Autowired
    private CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from user where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, CONCAT('ROLE_' , r.role) from user u inner join role r on u.idRole = r.idRole where lower(u.username) = lower(?)");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
        //Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS files.
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/static/**","/users/{\\d+}/password/recover","/users/{\\d+}/token/{\\d+}/password/temporary")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/users/{\\d+}/token/{\\d+}/password/temporary");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<Role> roles=roleServices.getRoles();
        //Retrieve array of roles(only string field without id)
        String[] rolesArray = new String[roles.size()];
        int i=0;
        for (Role role:roles){
            rolesArray[i++] = role.getRole();
        }

        http
           .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
           .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(rolesArray)//.authenticated()
        .and()//Login Form configuration for all others
           .formLogin()
           .loginPage("/login").successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
        //important because otherwise it goes in a loop because login page require authentication and authentication require login page
           .permitAll()
        .and()
           .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
           .logout()
           .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
           .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "JSESSIONID")
           .invalidateHttpSession(true)
           .permitAll()
        .and()
           .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/login")
        .and()
           .addFilterAfter(new MultiTenancyInterceptor(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

            }
        }
```

I added `MultiTenancyInterceptor` filter where I set the Tenant

```
@Component
public class MultiTenancyInterceptor extends OncePerRequestFilter   {

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {  
        String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(url);
            String domain = uri.getHost();
            if(domain!=null){
                TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(domain);
            }   
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   
}
```

but as I write the controller of login page doesn't receive the call:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage(){
    return "login";
}
```

Do you see an error in my `configure` method? If you need further information I can add the other classes. Thanks
PS: I noticed that `doFilter` is called twice for each page request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggest of **dur** I add the code

```
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

at the end of filter method

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to implement Filter inteface and do some your url logic and then forward it to next action using **filterChain.doFilter(request, response);**
Make sure to add this filter in web.xml.

Either way is you can use spring **org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter** for pre and post handling for http requests. Spring internally forwards to next controller request method.

Example : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/

Comment: HandlerInterceptorAdapter doesn't work with spring security

Comment: Hi @luca I have used filter to get tenantId but getting 401 exception.can you pls help me out.

Comment: it's too generic  as problem, maybe an authentication credentials problem